# control mount order of partitions on a USB disk in linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, usb-storage

I have a backup external hard drive in a USB box that is identical to my laptop's boot drive so that I can swap it in if my boot drive fails.  When it's connected to the system for normal use (e.g., backup, accessing files that don't fit on my SSD), I'd like to mount it like this:

```
/something/     (partition 1 mounts here)
/something/home (partition 3 mounts here)
                (partition 2 is swap, not used in this config)
```

This will make the filesystem look identical to the one on my boot disk, when mounted.  Also, I want it to automount.

I have in /etc/fstab:

```
LABEL=ht10oa1 /media/ext        ext4    commit=120,defaults,nofail,user 0    2
LABEL=ht10oa3 /media/ext/home   ext4    commit=120,defaults,nofail,user 0    2
```

This works half the time.  The other half, /media/ext/home mounts first, and /media/ext mounts over it, hiding the contents.  Not good.

How can I ensure that /media/ext mounts first?  I'm looking for simple here (I would think this should be automatic, as it is at boot time).  If it matters, it's on Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks,

--jh--

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use UUID to mount device from `/etc/fstab`. UUID are not subject to detection order. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/) is a better explanation on how to do that.

Comment: This did not work.  The partitions still mount in random order.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem, now I get it!